# Dynamic page on ionic framework or phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm a new mobile app developer who try to create an app using phonegap. Then I found ionic framework which is very useful framework and I want to work on it.

I have a question to ask you about how to make a dynamic page on mobile app using html and javascript which is related to the framework I use.

I use to create PHP web application before and when I need to make a dynamic page I just pass some parameter, e.g. `http://www.url.com/place.php?pid=20` which show the information about place `id=20` on that page.

In place.php I just use SQL command like

```
SELECT * FROM place WHERE pid=$pid
```

to make sure that my page show my the information dynamically.

But when I work on HTML5 and javascript I found that I can't pass any parameter over the URL like PHP.

So I would like to ask you the way to create the dynamic page like *place.php?pid=20* but it work on HTML5 and Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're making a mobile app, your html and Javascript files are baked into the app files. That is, when the user downloads the app, they download all the files that come with it.

So the best way to make an app dynamic is to use XHR and load only whatever dynamic content you need. Take a look at the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to see how to do this in Ionic.